# Event from BlocProvider in MultiBlocProvider are not sent at screen load. Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm still very new to Flutter and Bloc in general and I'm stuck in understanding this .

When app starts I get the print in console as expected :

> flutter: Event is AppStarted flutter: Transaction is Transition {
>   currentState: Uninitialized, event: AppStarted, nextState:
>   Authenticated }

from :

```
runApp(
    BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
        create: (context) {
          return AuthenticationBloc(
            userRepository: UserRepository(),
          )..add(AppStarted());
        },
        child:
```

but when `MapScreen` loads I don't get any:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
//        BlocProvider<AlertBloc>(
//          create: (context) {
//            return AlertBloc(alertRepository: FirebaseAlertRepository())
//              ..add(LoadAlerts());
//          },
//        ),
        BlocProvider<MapBloc>(create: (context) {
          return MapBloc(mapRepository: MapRepository())
            ..add(GetLocationStream())
            ..add(CenterMap());
        }),
      ],
      child: Scaffold
```

I do get prints instead when I add an event from `onPressed` callback:

```
onPressed: () {
                              BlocProvider.of<MapBloc>(context)
                                  .add(CenterMap());
                            },
```

> flutter: Event is Instance of 'GetLocationStream' flutter: Event is
>   Instance of 'CenterMap' flutter: Event is Instance of 'CenterMap'

Are the first two events the ones I added via the `BlocProvider`?

I realised the problem because, at screen loading I don't get prints for repository methods I call in `MapBloc`, but I do as soon I tap on the button as well as I get state prints:

> flutter: Transaction is Transition { currentState: MapCentered
>   {location: null, locationStream: null}, event: Instance of
>   'CenterMap', nextState: MapCentered {location: null, locationStream:
>   null} }

Does adding events from `BlocProvider` work differently when the are in a `MultiBlocProvider`?

Thank you very much.
Cheers.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever get a solution?

Comment: @Alex hi, I'm afraid I can't remember what the problem was. Very unusually I haven't published the solution I applied.. let me have a look at the code and see if I can reconstruct what I did..

Comment: @alex well, my code changed completely so I'm not sure what the problem was. I don't have a MapBloc anymore.. try describe your problem with some code..let see if I can help

Comment: I found the problem, in my case was simply the lazy property, thanks!